# How can I have an array of the html content of a JQuery element?

Tags: jquery, arrays, innerhtml

I want to have the inner html of a series of elements. This is what I tried:

```
slides = $("#slides p");
```

It gives me a series of objects, but I want the raw html of each! I tried `$("#slides p").html()` but it gives the first paragraph.

Comment: "but it breaks the first paragraph to letters" ...what do you mean by this? It's unclear what problem you are describing. An example would help a lot. `.html()` should be precisely what you need, in theory, but it will only get the first matched element (as per the first line of the [documentation page](https://api.jquery.com/html/)). If there are multiple `p` elements and you need the inner HTML of each one separately, then you'll need to loop.

Comment: It shouldn't break the first paragraph into letters... how are you using it?

Comment: I guess when I treat the returned string as array it is the array of chars

Comment: well if you treat a string as an array that is what you get, yes. But why would you process a string as if it was an array?

Comment: Because I supposed it's an array of inner html of each matched element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the collection, convert it to an array with [`.toArray`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) and then use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over it and get the inner HTML of each item.

```js
const ptext = $('#slides p').toArray().map(p => p.innerHTML);
console.log(ptext);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slides">
  <p>Peter</p>
  <p>Ray</p>
  <p>Egon</p>
  <p>Winston</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an array of strings. Each string element contains the innerHTML of a paragraph:

```
slides = $.makeArray($("#slides p").map(p=>p.innerHTML));
```

As `.map()` would still return a jquery object, `makeArray()` converts that into an array.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation page](https://api.jquery.com/html/), `.html()` only returns the contents of the first element in the set which your selector matched.

If you have multiple `p` elements and you need the contents of each one, then you need to iterate them:

```js
var slides = $("#slides p");
slides.each(function(i, el) {
  console.log(el.innerHTML);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slides">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
  <p>D</p>
</div>
```